# JSON:API library for MongoDB in .Net Core

Tags: .net, mongodb, .net-core, json-api

I would like to implement a JSON:API back-end service for my client application. All data is saved in MongoDB and I already implemented a generic data service for simple data interactions like CRUD. Is there any library or a way to do that in .net core? I saw this library: https://github.com/json-api-dotnet/JsonApiDotNetCore but if I am not mistaken it is not proper for MongoDB and I do not want to use DBContext. I am pretty new with JSON:API and MongoDB, I hope I have explained my requirement.

Comment: Are you sure that `JsonApiDotNetCore` must use `DBContext`? The docs are talking about [manually constructing a resource graph](https://json-api-dotnet.github.io/JsonApiDotNetCore/usage/resource-graph.html#manual-specification) as an alternative to Entity Framework DbContext if I got it right.

Answer (score 0):

I am going also to follow this video series that at first check looks nice:

[video series using JSON:API](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KAMuo6K7VcE&feature=youtu.be)

[the git repo code of the serie videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KAMuo6K7VcE&feature=youtu.be)

I am not sure if you can use this library without `EFCore`, but this tuto show what you already have and them start with `serialization`, I thinks this is a good way to work with `JSObjectNotation`:

[micro tuto](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mongo-app?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio)

And here you hace exactly what you need, without using `DBContext`:

[JSON:API without DBContext](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/json-api-implemenation-in-net-core-without-using-dbcontext)

Also a recomendation; at business level, `MongoDB` should only use for big data, not for small projects.

Answer (score -1):

An extension to [JsonApiDotNetCore](https://github.com/json-api-dotnet/JsonApiDotNetCore) is available at https://github.com/json-api-dotnet/JsonApiDotNetCore.MongoDb, which works with v4.

This package implements the required MongoDB support:

> MongoDB support for JsonApiDotNetCore
>
> Plug-n-play implementation of `IResourceRepository<TResource, TId>` allowing you to use [MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.com/) with your [JsonApiDotNetCore](https://github.com/json-api-dotnet/JsonApiDotNetCore) APIs.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: I'm one of the maintainers of JsonApiDotNetCore and we released MongoDB support recently, so when I saw this question I thought I'd help out by pointing to it. I agree I could have added more info in the answer, but intentionally did not, to prevent duplicating information (which may change over time). If the link breaks, my answer becomes useless anyway. I don't think its fair to downvote my answer, which is the only one actually providing a solution to the question. If that's the attitude of moderating newcomers to StackOverflow, I'll think twice before answering a question again.